# Threads hang on getCallerClass (Native method)

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, tomcat7, tomcat8

I encountered stucked threads in tomcat logs.
We use java version 7.

The last 2 lines of stacktrace:

```
Aug 30, 2023 8:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve$MonitoredThread     interruptIfStuck
ARNING: Thread "ajp-apr-8280-exec-33" (id=990) has been interrupted because it was active for     129,456,677 milliseconds ...
    java.lang.Throwable
         at sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(Native Method)
         at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1479)
          ...
```

Why did the threads stuck?

Restarting tomcat helped.

Comment: The message “has been interrupted because it was active for     129,456,677 milliseconds” suggests that the assumption that the thread hangs is just a guess because whoever implemented this check could not imagine that an operation takes that long. However, this is not a proof that the thread truly hangs. And if it it doesn’t hang, finding it in the method `getCallerClass` when peeking into the stack trace after 129,456,677 milliseconds might be mere coincidence.

Comment: Usually we don't see such logs, this is unusual case. I want to understand what was a reason of long running or stucked thread

Comment: That’s the wrong question. As said, we don’t know whether the thread is really stuck or whether it is extraordinarily long running. How long do these threads run normally? What part of the software implemented this check & warning and what heuristic does it use? Why is running for a day and 11 hours (apparently) fine but running for a day, 11 hours, and 57½ minutes considered a problem? There should be a documentation about this warning and its rationale somewhere.

Comment: In tomcat there is settings StuckThreadDetectionValve in server.xml and it is set to 4 second. So if the thread takes longer than 4 sec happening interruption by tomcat. In our case interruption happened after long time. What was a reason for that?